Aligning first and last equal signs in align*
I want to connect the first and last equal signs in an align* environment.
The code I have is:
\begin{align*}
\sin^2 x(1 + \cot^2 x) &= 1 \\
\sin^2 x + \sin^2x \cot^2 x \\
\sin^2x + \sin^2x \cdot \cfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x} \\
\sin^2x + \cos^2x \\
1 &= 1
\end{align*}

I want to connect the equal sign from the first line to the last line like this:

The image above is just a screenshot of the align* environment put into a word processor with a line manually inserted. I'd like LaTeX to print that line automatically.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78304203/2777074
